# MySQL - Max wrong return value result

Tags: mysql

So im new to programming and mysql showing wrong max return value.The return I got is mouse Instead of monitor which having most expensive price [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DaCl.jpg).

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: It should be `SELECT MAX(price) as maxPrice...`

Answer (score 2):

It should be like following code:

```
SELECT MAX(price) as most_expensive from list_barang
```

Answer (score 0):

The feedback from me:

1. Make sure the data type for price is number
2. SELECT MAX(price) ....
   instead

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem :

It is returning wrong result because you are asking for wrong stuff from the database.

by saying

```sql
SELECT MAX(item_name) as most_expensive
FROM   list_barang;
```

you are telling database to fetch the [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) highest value in the **names** of the items, not the price.

#### FIX :

If you just want the highest price then you can use the method already told by others that is

```sql
SELECT    MAX(price) as most_expensive from list_barang;
```

otherwise if you also want the name of the product with the highest price then you can use the following query

```sql
SELECT   item_name,price
FROM     list_barang
WHERE    price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM list_barang);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the item name instead of price. That's why you are getting "mouse" as result.
Use this one:

```
SELECT MAX(price) as most_expensive_price from list_barang;
```